# Obtener valores de propiedades de un Objeto usando Object.values con validaciones javascript

Tags: javascript, json, bucle-for, validación, objeto

soy nuevo en javascript y mas que todo trabajndo con arrys de objetos estoy tratando de obtener todos los valores de una propiedad de un objeto json con object.values, para luego guardar esos valores en un arreglo.
el problema es que tengo validaciones previas con condicionales y al parecer el objeto no entra a las validaciones y no se como usar el object.values con validaciones previas

***Mi codigo***

```js
//Mi arreglo de objetos json
 let val = [
           {
            "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "1",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "NUMBER",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": 1,
            "campo" : "NUMBER1"
          },
          {
            "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "1",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "NUMBER",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": 1,
            "campo" : "NUMBER1"
          },
          {
            "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "1",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "NUMBER",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": 2,
            "campo" : "NUMBER2"
          },
          {
             "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "2",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "STRING",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": "dsdsdsd",
            "campo": "STRING1",
          },
          {
            "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "3",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "STRING",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": "sdasd",
            "campo" : "STRING2"

          },
          {
            "fila": "1",
            "idColumn": "4",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "STRING",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
            "campo" : "STRING1"
          },
          {
            "fila": "2",
            "idColumn": "1",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "STRING",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": "31/12/2020",
             "campo" : "STRING2"

          },
          {
            "fila": "2",
            "idColumn": "1",
            "nombre": "ORDEN",
            "tipo": "STRING",
            "tipoNull": "N",
            "valores": "sdsd",
            "campo" : "STRING1"
          }
                ]
                
let listavalores = [];

 for (let j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {             
   if((val[j].tipo ==='STRING') && (val[j].campo ==='STRING1')){
   //el problema es que con la validacion if de arriba solo deben        //aparecer 3 valores
   
    listavalores = Object.values(val).map(value =>value.valores);   
   //pero el listavalores me traen los 8 valores no entra a la            validacion   
                 }
                 }
 console.log("listavalores: ", listavalores)
```

intente poner Object.values(val[j]) pero no funciona, alguna sugerencia o alguna idea.
se que lo mas facil sería asi.

l

```
et valoresEsperados = [];   
                 for (let j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {   
                    if((val[j].tipo ==='STRING') && (val[j].campo ==='STRING1') ){   
                       valoresEsperados.push( val[j].valores);  
                 }  
}
```

pero al hacer esto me crea 3 objetos con cada valor, y lo que necesito es guardat todos esos valores en un unio arreglo, se puede corregir este error con el object.values().
muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo debes realizar la combinación de un **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)** y un **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** al momento de querer realizar los filtros

```js
const val = [
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "1",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "NUMBER",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: 1,
        campo: "NUMBER1"
      },
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "1",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "NUMBER",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: 1,
        campo: "NUMBER1"
      },
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "1",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "NUMBER",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: 2,
        campo: "NUMBER2"
      },
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "2",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "STRING",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: "dsdsdsd",
        campo: "STRING1"
      },
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "3",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "STRING",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: "sdasd",
        campo: "STRING2"
      },
      {
        fila: "1",
        idColumn: "4",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "STRING",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
        campo: "STRING1"
      },
      {
        fila: "2",
        idColumn: "1",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "STRING",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: "31/12/2020",
        campo: "STRING2"
      },
      {
        fila: "2",
        idColumn: "1",
        nombre: "ORDEN",
        tipo: "STRING",
        tipoNull: "N",
        valores: "sdsd",
        campo: "STRING1"
      }
    ];

    const out = val
      .filter((item) => item.tipo === "STRING" && item.campo === "STRING1")
      .map((item) => item.valores);
    console.log(out);
```

Mediante *filter* específicas los filtros que deseas agregar y con *map* devuelves un arreglo nuevo sólo con el campo valores de cada objeto dentro de un arreglo.

Nos comentas si te sirve :)

Comment: Muy bien, no me había fijado que solo quería la propiedad `valores`. +1

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió